# python pandas to excel error

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel

I have a dataframe that I want to export to Excel. I'm new to python and pandas so I need some help on this simple task.

```
df2.to_excel('C:\BT\stack_test3.xlsx')
```

Error message:

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\BT\stack_test3.xlsx'

Comment: Are you sure your code is correct? shouldn't you use something like this: `df2.to_excel(r'C:\BT\stack_test3.xlsx')`? As I think your path is wrong and python thinks you are writing to `c:` as your back slash has not been escaped .

Comment: Does adding `r` prefix fix your problem?

Comment: No , unfortunally not..any new ideas?

Comment: You could check the access permissions, also could you try a different extension like `.xls`, .xlsx uses openpyxl , and `.xls` extension uses xlwt, would be interesting to see if this is a problem with both libraries.

Comment: When i use .xls it works!!!

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer, I know nothing about those Excel libraries unfortunately and I have not been able to find anything specific about permissions or other issues. Hope you can still proceed with your work

Comment: I sometimes get this error when I am trying to write to a file that I have open.

Comment: I have tried writing to both closed and open files, the problem is still there though...

Answer (score 9):

You path is incorrect, because you have not escaped the slashes it thinks you are trying to write to the root of c: drive use the following:

```
df2.to_excel(r'C:\BT\stack_test3.xlsx')
```

The `r` makes the path a raw string and means you do not need to escape the slashes

**Edit**

It seems that there is some error with `openpyxl` as using

```
df2.to_excel(r'C:\BT\stack_test3.xls')
```

works which uses `xlwt`, I don't know enough about those packages so it could be either a permissions problem with `openpyxl` which I have not been able to find anything about or a bug.

Comment: @7stud it means to `c:\` if you like the root or base of the disk drive, Vista and above may not allow applications to write to the root of your system disk unless it has sufficient privileges

Comment: But the docs say... _Unlike Standard C, all unrecognized escape sequences are left in the string unchanged, i.e., the backslash is left in the string_; and if you try: `s = 'A\B\C'
print ord("\\")

for ch in s:
    print ord(ch)`  you will see the backslashes are in the string.  So the backslash should only create a problem if \B or \s is a recognized escape sequence, and neither is a recognized escape sequence.   The op should use raw strings regardless to avoid any potential problems, or use forward slashes, but I don't see how this particular path is problematic.

Comment: Or even simpler, try: `print len('A\B\C')`.  Compare to `print len('C:\b\a')`

Comment: @7stud I don't have the xls writer module but I did just try `to_csv' without the `r` prefix and got a `[Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename` error, adding the `r` prefix fixes it, incidentally the expanded path without `r` prefix did not expand the middle slash so c:\\BT\stack_test3.xlsx would be displayed, if adding `r` prefix does not solve your problem then I will delete my answer

Comment: Okay, the MS docs say, _if a backslash precedes a character that does not appear in the table, the compiler handles the undefined character as the character itself. For example, \c is treated as an c._  So the string `"C:\BT\stack_test3.xlsx"` is interpreted by windows as `C:BTstack_test3.xlsx`

Comment: @7stud I'm sure you are correct but in python it is a common error for file paths to either not use unix style forward slashes, or not escape back slashes, it is more readable and less error prone to use the `r` prefix. The real question is does this fix the problem so I will ask the OP

Comment: Even if this doesn't fix the OP's problem it could fix other peoples finding this question on google, so please don't delete it.

Comment: Just to be clear..Tried df2.to_excel(r'C:\BT\stack_test3.xlsx'), it did not solve my problem though

Comment: @jonas, Okay...then I'll undelete my answer, and you can see if that solves your problem.

Comment: _I don't have the xls writer module but I did just try to_csv' without the r` prefix and got a [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename error, adding the r prefix fixes it,_ What path did you use?

Comment: path : C:\BT\stack_test3.xlsx. A subfolder under C in windows

Answer (score 4):

I had an identical problem. Turns out it's because I had left the Excel file open whilst I was trying to write to it. Apparently it doesn't like that. If you have it open try closing it.

Answer (score 1):

To confirm...in case future readers stumble in this page...before complicating things make sure that the excel file you are trying to save is not already open or to be safe.

Just close all of excel and try save it again.

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should write to another drive like 'D:' because in Windows Vista or above that you have no permission to write to 'C:\' and you have no reason to earn the permission.

Answer (score -1):

After closing all instances of excel and running
python code works.